# how to get the model(a json form data) from a combobox in QT

Tags: c++, qt

My program use Model/View pattern. The question is that i want to get the json data from the combobox, but i get the null data.
This is my approach: the question is that *dept* return value is *QJsonObject(invalid)*.

```
    DeptTreeModel deptm = ui->comboBox_dept->model();
    QJsonDocument deptd = deptm.json();
    QJsonObject dept = deptd.object();
```

and this is my model definition:

```
#ifndef DEPTTREEMODEL_H
#define DEPTTREEMODEL_H

#include "src/qrest/models/jsonresttreemodel.h"
#include <QObject>

class DeptTreeModel : public JsonRestTreeModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    DeptTreeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
};

#endif // DEPTTREEMODEL_H
```

And this is my model:

```
#include "depttreemodel.h"
#include "global.h"

DeptTreeModel::DeptTreeModel(QObject *parent) : JsonRestTreeModel(parent)
{
    this->m_requests.setGet(GLOBAL->getUrl(Global::SystemUrls::DeptUrl));
    this->m_requests.setGetDetails(GLOBAL->getUrl(Global::SystemUrls::DeptUrl) + "/?id=");
}

int DeptTreeModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    return 1;
}

QVariant DeptTreeModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{


    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();


    QJsonTreeItem *item = static_cast<QJsonTreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());


    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {

        if (index.column() == 0) {

            return item->item().value("name");
                //return QString("%1").arg(item->key());
        }

    } else if (Qt::EditRole == role) {
        if (index.column() == 1) {
            return QString("%1").arg(item->value());
        }
    }



    return QVariant();
}
```

And this is my json data form:

```
"content": [
        {
            "createTime": "2019-03-25 11:04:50",
            "deptSort": 0,
            "enabled": true,
            "hasChildren": true,
            "id": 7,
            "label": "HuaNan",
            "leaf": false,
            "name": "HuaNan",
            "subCount": 2,
            "updateTime": "2020-05-10 19:59:12",
            "updatedBy": "admin"
        } ]
```

I want to get the property of "id" and "name" from this json data, but i cant read the model data in the combobox_dept, so i hope to get some solutions to get json object or "id" and "name" property from combobox_dept. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you think `DeptTreeModel deptm = ui->comboBox_dept->model();` actually does?  Hint: declare the `DeptTreeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)` as `explicit` and see what effect that has on compilation.

Comment: Excuse me, can you show me how to use **explicit**? Thank you.

Comment: Just declare it as `explicit DeptTreeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)` in the header.  In short, you're creating `deptm` as a `DeptTreeModel` instance with the model returned by `ui->comboBox_dept->model()` as its parent object.